# Split one monitor into 2 mirrored monitors with xrandr

Tags: linux, xrandr, multi-monitor

I'm in an odd predicament where I have one monitor that needs to be split into 2 monitors and mirrored. The splitting part is relatively easy as of XRandR 1.5 thanks  to `--setmonitor`, but I can't mirror the virtual monitors, as they don't actually appear in xrandr's list of monitors. At this point, I have no clue what exactly to do next. Although I'd like to keep this monitor setup to just xrandr, I would be willing to install any additional software, as long as it isn't too intrusive.